# Cloud Functions for Firebase Error: Forbidden

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, urlrequest

I am trying to send `multipart/form-data` through `URLRequest` on my app to Cloud Functions for Firebase. And to test if my cloud function and my app are connected, I created a test function and deployed it:

```
function test(data, callback) {
    console.log("Test begin:");
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Test finish...");
    callback(null, null);
}

exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, respond) => {
    console.log("test called");
    test(request.body.data, function(data, error) {
        respond.json({
            data: data, 
            error: error
        });
    });
});
```

However, after sending the `URLRequest`, nothing was printed on the console, and instead, I got a html as data. By opening the html, I get `Error: Forbidden. Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.` How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Doug Stevenson, the problem is that I used the wrong URL instead of the provided one. And the URL can be found on the console when you deploy your cloud function.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions has special ways of dealing with different types of input.  [It's documented here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_multipart_form_uploads).

For `multipart/form-data`, you can access the content as `request.rawBody`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for replying. I think the problem is that the cloud function I wrote didn't print anything to the console, in other words, it was never invoked. And it seems like I need to provide something to firebase or i will not be able to send request to it. But still, the link you provide is really helpful.

Comment: Are you using the URL that was printed to the console when you deployed?

Comment: I just tried the URL it provided, and it worked, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson I got the same problem despite I use a URL which I got from CLI. Don't you happen to know what might it be? Thanks.